# trying to recursively create an array of results from a json tree-like structure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures

I'm trying to get a list of the descendants for a specific person. Below is what i have so far:

```
function getDescendants(id, descendants){
    children = getChildren(id);
    if(children){
        for (var child in children) {
           if(children.hasOwnProperty(child)){
               descendants.push(getDescendants(children[child].id, descendants));
           }
        }
    }
    return getPersonById(id);
}
```

This works until it returns to the initial call and has forgotten the children array.

getChildren returns and array of child objects
getPersonById returns a person object

Any help/suggestions are appreciated

Comment: code is not logical, why not return `descendants` directly

Comment: @AbdelrhmanMohamed Ok imagine descendants isn't even passed in imagine its global...if instead we do this in the loop
`for (var child in children) {
      if(children.hasOwnProperty(child)){
          descendants.push(children[child]);
          getDescendants(children[child].id);
      }
  }`

Comment: let me get this straight, you need to remember the original array returned the first time `getChildren` is called? are you trying to make a b-tree by chance?

Comment: @ryan correct...but im not trying to make a b-tree just trying to traverse a tree while creating an array of results(descendants)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDescendants(id, descendants, originalChildren ){
    children = getChildren(id);
    if(children){
        var originalChildren = originalChildren || children;
        for (var child in children) {
           if(children.hasOwnProperty(child)){
               descendants.push(getDescendants(children[child].id, descendants, originalChildren ));
           }
        }
    }
    return getPersonById(id);
}
```

When you first call `getDescendants` pass `null` or just don't pass anything in the third slot. If it's null then it will store the value of `children` in the variable otherwise it'll store `originalChildren` each time and you'll keep passing that first instance of `children` through your function.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting some co-workers and a lot of brain pain this is what we came up with.

```
let getDescendants = (parentID, people) => {
    return people.filter((el)=>{
        return el.parents.indexOf(parentID) > -1;
    }).map((kid)=>{
        return [...getDescendants(kid.id, people), kid.id ];
    }).reduce((a, b) => {
        return a.concat(b);
    }, []);
}
```

Thank you all for the assistance